# The Expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native Expo modules are unavailable and this code is not running on Expo

Tags: react-native

I am trying to connect to the simulator but the response is coming this red screen. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Have you followed the URL shown in the error message? Have you installed all prerequisites? Please give some more details about what you've done before and when you encountered that error. Like "I installed the Expo SDK..."

Comment: incase anyone comes across this, i tried various things and finally fixed this by downgrading expo from 30.0.1 to 30.0.0

Comment: I had the same problem after upgrading expo-cli to 2.3.8... I downgraded to 2.3.5, which worked before, and the problem is gone...